# diagrams in beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-cd

I want to put this diagram in the latex when I make a `frame` it does not work but without `frame` it works right. Is there any idea?

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.50em]
\cdots\arrow[r]
  &D^{\oplus n_{i+1}}
  \arrow[rr,"d_{i+1}"]
  \arrow[dr,"g_{i+1}"]
  &&D^{\oplus n_i}
  \arrow[dr,"g_i"]
  \arrow[rr,"d_i"]
  &&D^{\oplus n_{i-1}}
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[dr]
  &\cdots\\
M_{i+1}\arrow[ur] 
  &&M_i
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i}"]
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  &&M_{i-1}
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i-1}"]
  &&M_{i-2} 
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`?

Comment: It worked with this [fragile] thanks. Is there any way that I make it smaller than now in the frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`frame`s in `beamer`  have problem with some things, such as the `&` in TikZ matrices. To get around that either add the `[fragile]` option to the frame, or use `ampersand replacement` as in the second example below.

In the code are indicated a few things that can help you reduce the size of the diagram, if you really need that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[
   column sep=0.50em,
%   row sep=small, % reduces space between rows
%   cramped, % reduces whitespace around cells
%   cells={font=\tiny} % reduces font size (try \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \small
  ]
\cdots\arrow[r]
  &D^{\oplus n_{i+1}}
  \arrow[rr,"d_{i+1}"]
  \arrow[dr,"g_{i+1}"]
  &&D^{\oplus n_i}
  \arrow[dr,"g_i"]
  \arrow[rr,"d_i"]
  &&D^{\oplus n_{i-1}}
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[dr]
  &\cdots\\
M_{i+1}\arrow[ur] 
  &&M_i
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i}"]
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  &&M_{i-1}
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i-1}"]
  &&M_{i-2} 
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[
   ampersand replacement=\&,
   column sep=0.50em,
%   row sep=small, % reduces space between rows
%   cramped, % reduces whitespace around cells
%   cells={font=\tiny} % reduces font size (try \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \small
  ]
\cdots\arrow[r]
  \&D^{\oplus n_{i+1}}
  \arrow[rr,"d_{i+1}"]
  \arrow[dr,"g_{i+1}"]
  \&\&D^{\oplus n_i}
  \arrow[dr,"g_i"]
  \arrow[rr,"d_i"]
  \&\&D^{\oplus n_{i-1}}
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[dr]
  \&\cdots\\
M_{i+1}\arrow[ur] 
  \&\&M_i
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i}"]
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  \&\&M_{i-1}
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
  \arrow[ur,"f_{i-1}"]
  \&\&M_{i-2} 
  \arrow[dashed,ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```